# prestashop -How to find out if a product is available for sale or not

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I need to know is my product is available for sale or not . I searched alot in product table but I don't know which cell is showing  that  how many of this product is available and is it for sale or not at all .

How can I find it out from mysql database of prestashop ?

Comment: quantity is work as well for providing details that product is in stock or not.

Comment: @urfusion thanks for reply but I think it's not related to quantity . I check a product in website and quantity was 0 but I can order it also

Answer (score 1):

You can check product availability by calling `checkQty()` in the Product Class

```
$prod = new Product($idProduct);
$available = $prod->checkQty();
```

If you want to do that via SQL, you have to check two things :

- In `prefix_stock_available`, make sure `quantity` is not at zero (quantity = sum of all combination's qty)
- In `prefix_stock_available`, if `out_of_stock`

  - equals `0`, it means the product will NOT allow new orders if not enough quantity
  - equals `1`, it means the product will allow new orders if not enough quantity
  - equals `2`, it means that the product behaviour is defined by the global setting you can find in `prefix_configuration` at the key `PS_ORDER_OUT_OF_STOCK` so you have to check that one too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to get only the active products through MySql query. Remember replacing the **PS_PREFIX** for the real prefix. The default prefix is - *ps* - , but for security reasons, it is recomendable change it:

```
SELECT * FROM `PS_PREFIX_product` WHERE `active` = 1 AND `available_for_order` = 1
```

Now, you can change the query to apply some filter to get the result that you need. For example, checking if some product is available. In this case, you would have to replace the **PRODUCT_ID** for a real number:

```
SELECT * FROM `PS_PREFIX_product` WHERE `active` = 1 AND `available_for_order` = 1 AND `id_product` = PRODUCT_ID
```